# jQuery timepicker slider not working after upgrading jQuery to 1.11.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We just upgraded the jquery version in our application. After upgrade, slider in time picker stopped working.

The error I get is

```
Error: TypeError: e is undefined
Source File: jquery.js line 338 > eval
```

Please help.

Comment: See browser console for errors!

Comment: with jquery1.9.1, also add `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: We have added the migrate scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.9, the old deprecated $.browser function was removed, and perhaps other deprecated functions as well. Many errors about jQuery 1.9 upgrade are related to this. Does the console throws an error related to $.browser ?

Either keep an older jQuery version (up to 1.8.3), or use the "jQuery Migrate" plugin which will add the $.browser support.